# Install Modx on FTP Server

Tags: joomla, ftp, web, content-management-system, modx-revolution

I am pretty new to cms and hope you can help me. I'd like to install `modx` on a ftp server. My problem is my predecessor created a website with `joomla`. Now I want to create a completely new website out of the old one (just content, layout and design will be new), but with `modx`. I know how to built it, but i do not understand how to install `modx` and building the new website without crashing the existing.

Can someone give me a little step by step (if possible as simple as you can, cause i'm really not so familiar to the topic) on where to install (some kind of subdirectory?!); and what i have to adjust in `modx` so while developing  the old website can be used without some kind of crossing (or if possible, to install modx localy on a flashdrive and upload the website somehow when finished?).

And how, if the website is finished, to delete the old one (deinstall joomla,...) and get the new one to the root directory.

Ps. Sorry for my English, isn't the best... I am a German :)

Thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

I you have access to the server management or some kind of control panel, I would suggest create a new subdomain, such as `new.yourdomain.com` and install MODx there. I would also suggest using a separate database, evenou though that is not crucial as you can use the default `modx_` prefix to easily tell one set of tables from the old joomla ones.

Once you are happy with the new site, either transfer it:

http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/moving-your-site-to-a-new-server

or just change the DNS of your server to point the main domain to the new subdirectory. That would depend on your hosting prvider.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I started to update the website with joomla because nobody answered my question, but when it is up to date I will start to make it as you said :) does not seem to be that difficult :D I am just worried about crashing everything :/